# What does the "\" mean in this statement about regular languages?

Tags: notation, automata, regular-language, regular-expressions

[image]
I have having difficulty finding the meaning of the backslash in the statement. I don't know if it could be a division, an OR operator or something else. If someone could provide information about it, that would be very helpful!

Comment: in elementary set theory, $\setminus$ means set difference:  $U\setminus A$ is the set of elements of $U$ that are not in $A$

Comment: [Set difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_(set_theory)): "remove" from the first set the two elements $aa$ and $bb$.

Comment: $\setminus$ is `$\setminus$`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The backslash like symbol is used to indicate elements present in set A and not in set B, in the case of A\B. In your question {aa,ab,ba,bb} \ {aa,bb}, the elements aa and bb are present in both sets, so they are excluded. Thus the answer is the remaining elements in the first set which are ab and ba.